# i am trying to console log an array from the ticket master API but can only seem to log 1 item from the array

Tags: jquery, api, console.log, ticketmaster

I am currently trying to get all event names to populate in my console log, but I can only get one to show. I understand why I am only showing 1 result(because I chose object 0 in the array), but I am unsure how to get them all to show

code below
`console.log("event:" + response._embedded.events[0].name);`

[pic of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LDFU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
console.table(response._embedded.events, ["name"])
```

Comment: @RES3127 no problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
console.log("events: " + response._embedded.events.map(e => e.name));
```